# Mail attachment in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a mail after my pipe ends that will include some logs that I'm collecting

```
            emailext subject: "${env.JOB_NAME}  #" + env.BUILD_NUMBER + " - " + currentBuild.currentResult + " for branch: " + branch_Name + "  commit: " + "${git_commit_hash}", body: """
                Installation :  ${create_cluster_result}
                unit test results: ${run_unit_tests_result}
                error logs: ${error_logs}
                
               """, attachLog: true, attachmentsPattern: "${error_logs}", to: "$extendedEmailRec"
```

but I get only one attachment, build.log. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "${error_logs}" is the path to only one log file. You can always use wildcards in your pattern as well. For e.g. considering error_logs as your logs directory: (***.log** in code below)

```
       """, attachLog: true, attachmentsPattern: "${error_logs}/*.log", to: "$extendedEmailRec"
```

This way you can end up with as many files with .log extension in your attachments.